# Socket io namespaces do not fire on("connection") event

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io both (server API and client API) on Node.js as client and server. This is possible as specified in the [docs](https://socket.io/docs/)). I am not using any particular frameworks except Express and followed the [official guide](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express) for using socket.io with it.

On the server side I have:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
server = http.Server(app);

const io = require("socket.io")(server) //server listens on "http://localhost:3001
io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("server says: someone connected");
});
```

On the client side I have:

```js
const io = require("socket.io-client")("http://localhost:3001");
io.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("client says: connected");
});
```

Until here everything works fine... Now when adding namespaces nothing seem to work anylonger. I followed the [official guide](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) and ended up with the following:

On the server side I have:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
server = http.Server(app);

const io = require("socket.io")(server) //server listens on "http://localhost:3001
const nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');
nsp.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("server says: someone connected");
});
```

On the client side I have:

```
const io = require("socket.io-client")("http://localhost:3001");
const socket = io('/my-namespace');
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("client says: connected");
});
```

But the after the introduction of namespaces nothing seems to work... What am I missing?!

Thanks I am completely lost

Comment: Isn't this a typo? `cont nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');`?

Comment: I edited the question, I had no typo in my code, so I still did not solve the problem